# Drivers for Nvidia GTX970M

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I have a problem that may sound already heard, but I can't find a proper driver for my Clevo laptop with a GTX970M, using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit uefi, here are the ways I tried:

- Installed version 346.35 from xorg-edgers ppa, here is what I get: initially seems a normal boot, but after boot logo some coloured pixels appear on the screen then it becomes completely black. I can hear the login page welcome sound, and I can even log in (without seeing what happens underneath) but all I can do is switching to command line and uninstall drivers, then reboot and everything works on integrated graphics.
- Installing official drivers (346.35) from Nvidia website manually (following the right procedure) leads to a normal boot, login window, I can type my password and log in, then it  stuck on this: [image: no desktop]
  and all I can do is repeat the same procedure as the first point and rely upon integrated graphics again.

Comment: Can you log in to the guest session?  Have you tried rolling back to 340.76 with the xorg-edgers?

Comment: Thank you for helping! Guest does the same the as regular user, 340.76 doesn't support gtx970m.

Comment: Luca, as you don't have enough reputation to go in chat:  1/ can you disable the gtx970 in the BIOS or do you have to remove it physically from the machine?  2/ Do you have a [system back-up](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) You've been promoted to user type 4!  ;-)

Comment: No, I can't remove nor disable it.

Comment: There are some problems related to bbswitch with gtx970m. To make it suspend properly take a look at this issue.
https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch/issues/115

Answer (score 1):

The answer is outdated, now the GTX9xx series works fine with the drivers in Ubuntu's repositories.

Anyway, if you want the latest drivers you could try this PPA instead: **https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa**

<s>Finally solved using this ppa instead of xorg-edger's one:</s>

**https://launchpad.net/~mamarley/+archive/ubuntu/nvidia**

and installing:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends nvidia-346 bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-prime nvidia-346-uvm
```

Comment: This PPA has been deleted.

Comment: Yes, the drivers in the Ubuntu's repositories work just fine, but if you want the latest drivers you could try this PPA instead: **https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa**

Comment: Maybe you want to [edit] your answer to add that fact. :-)